# Mysql - Select based on multiple row conditions

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have this:

```
|ID | Val |  
+---+-----+  
| 1 |  10 |  
| 1 |  20 |  
| 1 |  30 |  
| 2 |  10 |  
| 2 |  20 |  
| 3 |  20 |  
| 3 |  30 |  
+---+-----+
```

And I need to select only those ID-s that have both 10 and 30 values. So, in English, give me an ID that has both 10 and 30 values. 
How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will use something like this:

```
select id
from yourtable
where val in (10, 30)
group by id
having count(distinct val) =2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b451d/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `ID` FROM tablename WHERE `VAL` IN ('10','30');
```